# How do I convert an array of nested objects into a String?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to convert a nested array of Objects into a String. How do I do this?

I have tried the .toString() method but that just returns [Object object], which is not what I want.

My array looks like this:

```
[[
{"incr":261,"decr":547},
{"incr":259,"decr":549}
],
[{"incr":254,"decr":547}]
]
```

And I want to be able to convert it into a String that looks exactly like that.

Comment: Take a look to [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can use `space` third argument (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument) of the `JSON.stringify()` to format the result with identation: `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind?

```js
const data = [
  [{ incr: 261, decr: 547 }, { incr: 259, decr: 549 }],
  [{ incr: 254, decr: 547 }]
];

// like this?
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
// or maybe like this with some more control over how you generate the string?
console.log(data.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []).map(({ incr, decr }) => `Increase: ${incr} - decrease: ${decr}`).join(', '))
```